# iGUI for Unity 3D

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Well,I am working on my graduation project with unity 3d pro v4.5.0 ..I was using the normal method OnGUI() in my scripts but now i want to make a better interface for my project and i didn't anderstand how can i replace for example  these lines in  my "Database" Script:

```
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Add to database")) 
            {     
                    // Insert the data 
                    InsertRow (FirstName,LastName); 
                    // And update the readout of the database 
                    databaseData = ReadFullTable (); 

             }
```

With just calling a Button1_click for example from my iGUI Class specially that every thing related to interface and buttons exists in OnGUI() method so how can i change all of that in my "Database" Script..i did anderstand how to make a button in iGUI that LOAD a scene or set an other function in the same iGUI Class but i just want to make buttons and iGUI field texts in iGUI MonoBehaviour Class and call them later whenever i need in my pricipal script "Database" if it is possible.Please am so in need for help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That wasn't particularly comprehensible, however I suggest if you are struggling with the old OnGUI system: do yourself a favour and upgrade to Unity 4.6 or 5 and use the new UnityEngine.UI system. It's much easier to use, more powerful and much more performant.

Comment: thank you   Huacanacha  for your help, but it's okay i find out how simple it was throught this link:  http://avamstudios.com/77-accessing-igui-elements-any-script/       ...My mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You need do this:

1. create a public method in any script.
2. add the script to a GameObject.
3. Click the button and add the object with the script in the method
   OnClick located in the inspector.
4. Choose your script and the public method where said No function.
   Boala!!, when you click, your method run.